# iptables and modules priority

Tags: kernel, iptables, kernel-module

I am still wondering which comes in the first priority. "Iptables" or "Kernel Modules"?

With the help ip iptables, say

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j thoTPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 3000
```

I am redirecting the packets to port 3000. I am doing this on system startup. In my kernel module I am getting all the packets in preroute itself and processing for my needs and return back to the kernel.

```
  if( nf_register_hook(&pac_preroute_hook_ops) < 0 ) {
        printk("Failed to register pac_preroute_hook_ops.");
        return -1;
    }
```

if a port 80 packet comes to the box, which comes in priority ? It first follow the iptables rule or directly like all the other packets it goes into my custom module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iptables is the userland interface that handles the kernel module "Netfilter"
then both cases you mention would be using the same hook.